# How to unit test code that depends on a Factory

Tags: c#, unit-testing, factory

I have a DataService class like below

```
public class LessonDataService
{

    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork = UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork();

    public Lesson FindById(int id)
    {
        try
        {
            return unitOfWork.Lessons.FindById(id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see the UnitOfWork is constructed inside of the DataService class. I also don't want the pass the UnitOfWork through constructor, I don't want the UI code to bother with UnitOfWork I just want it to call the DataService class and let it do the rest. Any ideas?

Comment: Using static factories tends to make testing their dependents in isolation more difficult than they need to be. You are correct in that the UI should not be concerned with the UOW. it is however concerned with the data service.

Comment: Can you inject some dependency into the `UnitOfWorkFactory`?

Answer (score 6):

> How to unit test code that depends on a Factory

Short Answer: **You Don't**.

[Abstract Factories are a code smell](https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=100)

Tightly coupled code is difficult to test. (but not impossible).

Refactor your code for explicit dependency via constructor injection. (avoid service locator anti-pattern)

```
public class LessonDataService : ILessonDataService {    
    private readonly IUnitOfWork unitOfWork;

    public LessonDataService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork) {
        this.unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    }

    public Lesson FindById(int id) {
        try {
            return unitOfWork.Lessons.FindById(id);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw exception;
        }
    }
}
```

> I don't want the UI code to bother with UnitOfWork I just want it to call the DataService class and let it do the rest.

Then abstract the service, inject that into the UI and let it do the rest. The UI should not be directly concerned with the UOW.

```
public interface ILessonDataService  {
    Lesson FindById(int id);
}
```

By refactoring to depend on explicit abstractions, the code is now more flexible and can be tested in isolation with minimal negative effects.

```
[TestMethod]
public void DataService_Should_Get_Lesson() {
    //Arrange
    var id = 1;
    var lesson = new Lesson {
        Id = id,
        //...code removed for brevity
    };
    var mock = new Mock<IUnitOfWork>();
    mock.Setup(_ => _.Lessons.FindById(id)).Returns(lesson);

    var sut = new LessonDataService(mock.Object);

    //Act
    var actual = sut.FindById(id);

    //Assert
    lession.Should().BeEquivalentTo(actual);
}
```

In production code the current factory could still be registered with the DI container in the composition root, yet still keeps the code decoupled.

For example (in .Net Core)

```
services.AddTransient<IUnitOfWork>(_ => UnitOfWorkFactory.CreateUnitOfWork());
services.AddTransient<ILessonDataService, LessonDataService>();
```

Comment: Unfortunately I can't change the Factory class and export the UnitOfWork for political reasons, but thanks a lot for your effort.

Comment: @Sisyphus, I haven't changed the factory class at all. I've refactored the code that depends on the factory class. Is that what you meant by being unable to change the code?

Comment: I am sorry I didn't mean change the factory, I mean exposing the UnitOfWork to presentation. We need it completely encapsulated inside the DataService class and the presentation be totally ignorant even of its abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Mocking framework. Unit tests are meant to test the piece of code not the branches or connected classes. Use mock framework like Mockito or easymock, mock the `UnitOfWorkFactory` and create your own output for `unitOfWork.Lessons.FindById(id)`. Remember to test all possibilities. Use this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mockito/) to learn more about Mockito.

Comment: I am using Moq already, but if i mock the UnitOfWorkFactory how do i inject it inside the DataService class so that i uses it instead of using the real Factory.

Answer (score 0):

What I settled for is that I make an **Internal** constructor for the `DataService` and make it visible to unit tests project using `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` so that I can override the factory and inject and Mock UnitOfWork.